# Receiving Push Notification from multiple independent senders

Tags: cordova, firebase, mobile, push-notification

I'am currently developing an app for an open-source social network. The network can be operated on your own server.

Ideally the app should allow users too add social-network instances on demand, so users can add for example our community site and an own network instance and receive notifications from both backends.

Is it somehow possible to receive push notifications from multiple independent senders?

In the firebase cloud documentation I've found this section: [Receiving messages from multiple senders](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multiple-senders)

This suggests, that there can be multiple senders for one app, but I did not find any further information on how to implement this on sender side, and if this is suitable for my usecase:

> To make this possible, make sure each sender generates its own sender ID. See the client documentation for your platform for information on on how to obtain the FCM sender ID

Is an independent party able to create a own FCM project with a `sender id` and send notifications to specific devices with our social network app installed?

Also does the following line mean, 100 multiple sender per receiver or 100 multiple sender per app:

> Note that there is limit of 100 multiple senders.

I also considered [OpenSignal](https://onesignal.com/).
Perhaps It is possible to initialize multiple sender by means of [startInit](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/cordova-sdk#section--startinit-), but I assume that onesignal is also restricted to one project per app.

In general I see the following possibilities for the app, but I'am not sure which of them are feasible:

1. One app in the marketplace which is connected to one FCM or OneSignal project which will be served by multiple sender.
2. One app in the marketplace which is connected to multiple OneSignal projects each with one sender backend. (I assume FCM does not support this)
3. Provide an app template for users to create own Apps connected to one FCM or OneSignal project.

Would be great if someone can share some experiences or suggestions regarding this issue, perhaps there are even other solutions available.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and not specifically about programming or a programming issue. Also, when you say 'on your own server' is the thinking to run Firebase on your own server? If so, Firebase is not the right solution as it cannot be installed independently. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I meant that our platform can be installed on an own server, just to clarify that those installations are independent from us. It's more of a question if its technical feasible to have many independent google projects sending push notifications to a single app.